# Grunt file only watching changes in HTML

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I am trying to set up a grunt file to watch for changes in in multiple files, like sass, javascript and HTML. Currently it only watches changes that are made to the HTML file. I set this up based on a tutorial I found and it seemed to work just fine for them, but it does not work for me. Does any one know what I am doing wrong? This is the first time I have worked with grunt.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
  grunt.initConfig({
      uglify: {
        my_target: {
          files: {
            '_/js/script.js' : ['_js/components/js*.js'],
          }//files
        }//my_target
      },//uglify
      compass: {
        dev: {
          options: {
            config: 'config.rb'
          }//options
        }//dev
      },//compass
      watch: {
        options: { livereload: true },
        scripts: {
            files: ['_components/js/*.js'],
            task: ['uglify']
        }, //script
        sass: {
            files: ['_components/sass/*.scss'],
            task: ['compass:dev']
        }, //sass
        html: {
            files: ['*.html']
        }, //html
    }, //watch
  });//initConfig
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch', 'compass:dev']);
};//exports
```

Comment: Not a Grunt expert, but I think watch uses tasks not task.

Comment: Both `loadNpmTasks` and `registerTask` are valid syntax in grunt.

Comment: If you run just `uglify` or `compass` alone, do they work correctly?

Comment: Running the task(s) with the `--verbose` option is usually helpful in debugging. What is the output of the task when run with that option?

Comment: I have changed it to read tasks not task. Mathew, it does not seem to work when I tell it to only watch compass or uglify.